# Dynamically creating classes in python and __repr__

Tags: python

This is a fairly straightforward question hopefully you all can enlighten me.  In the example below how do I define __repr__ to be dynamically set to self.name?

Thanks all!

```
import re

inputlist = 'Project="Sparcy" Desc=""\nProject="Libs" Desc=""\nProject="Darwin" Desc=""\nProject="Aaple" Desc="The big project"'

regex = re.compile('([^ =]+) *= *("[^"]*"|[^ ]*)')

results = []
for project in inputlist.split("\n"):
    items = [ (k.strip(), v.strip()) for k, v in regex.findall(project)]
    if len(items) < 2:
        print("Houston we have a problem - Only %s k/v pair found for %s" % (len(items), project))
        continue
    item_dict = dict(items[1:])
    item_dict['name'] = items[0][1]
    klass = type(items[0][0], (object,), item_dict)
    results.append(klass)

print results
```

What I am looking for is this

psuedo code

```
for result in results
 type(result) → Project
 print result → Sparky
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want

```
print results
```

to return

```
["Sparcy", "Libs", "Darwin", "Aaple"]
```

1. Printing a list shows the repr of its elements.
2. `repr(elt)` is determined by `type(elt).__repr__`.
3. Since in this case the elements are classes, you need to set the
   `__repr__` for the type of the class.

---

```
import re

inputlist = '''\
Project="Sparcy" Desc=""
Project="Libs" Desc=""
Project="Darwin" Desc=""
Project="Aaple" Desc="The big project"
Site="Phoenix" Protocol="Cheese"'''

regex = re.compile('([^ =]+) *= *("[^"]*"|[^ ]*)')

results = []
for project in inputlist.split("\n"):
    items = [ (k.strip(), v.strip()) for k, v in regex.findall(project)]
    if len(items) < 2:
        print("Houston we have a problem - Only %s k/v pair found for %s" % (len(items), project))
        continue
    item_dict = dict(items[1:])
    item_dict['name'] = items[0][1]
    projectname=items[0][0]
    metametaklass=type('meta_'+projectname,(type,),{'__repr__':lambda cls: cls.__name__}) 
    metaklass=metametaklass(projectname,(type,),{'__repr__':lambda cls: cls.name})
    klass=metaklass(projectname+'_class', (object,), item_dict)
    results.append(klass)

print(results)
```

yields

```
["Sparcy", "Libs", "Darwin", "Aaple", "Phoenix"]
```

and

```
for result in results:
    print(type(result))
    print(result)    
    print('-'*80)
```

yields

```
Project
"Sparcy"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Project
"Libs"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Project
"Darwin"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Project
"Aaple"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Site
"Phoenix"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

PS. Note that this is a perversion of `__repr__`, since the `repr` of an object is supposed to be an unambiguous string representation of the object. That is, it is supposed to give enough information to reproduce the object. You probably should be defining a different `print` function instead of messing with metaclasses.

Comment: Do you know how to be able to define the type.  The way I understand this works is if `__metaclass__` is defined it will use that. You are taking advantage of that for the `__repr__`.  How do I not propagate that for `__metaclass__`.  The __goal  → type(Sparky) == Project__

Comment: @rh0dium: I'm not sure I understand the question. I edited my post so `print(type(klass))` would print `Project`.

Comment: But then it's no longer dynamic.  What happens when you thow at it this..  `inputlist = 'Site="Phoenix" Protocol="Cheese"\n`